# Delete row if first letter in cell is a letter

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to loop through a range in column A and delete each row where the value in cell A starts with a letter (e.g. delete C159, but not 8T9G3). I think the code may work correctly, if I get the between piece straight. Any suggestions how I can get the code to work?

```
Sub DeleteLetterRows()

Dim k as integer

For k = 2 To 100
    If Asc(ActiveSheet.Range("A" & k).value) >=65 and <=90 or >=97 and <=122
        Rows(k).EntireRow.Delete
    Else
    End If
Next k

End Sub
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some issues:

- When you delete a row, and *k* increases, you actually skip a row, which you don't check. So, better go downwards with *k* to avoid this problem.
- The way you compare against ASCII values has wrong syntax, as you need to explicitly specify a value after *and* immediately before each `>=` and `<=` operator. But instead of giving a correction (which would be long), I'll suggest a shorter syntax:
- Checking for a letter can be done in a more readable way, which does not require the knowledge of ASCII codes. Simply check if the first character is different when put in upper case than when put in lower case. If so, it is a letter.
- You are missing the `Then` keyword at the end of the `If` line;

Code:

```
Sub DeleteLetterRows()    
    Dim k as integer
    Dim l as String    
    For k = 100 To 2 Step -1
        l = Left(ActiveSheet.Range("A" & k).value, 1)
        If UCase(l) <> LCase(l) Then
            Rows(k).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next k    
End Sub
```

Comment: note that the closing bracket after .value should not be there, but I do not know how to edit it.

Comment: Ah, yes, I just removed that bad bracket now. Thanks for mentioning it.

Answer (score 1):

To check the first character of your string you use the function Left(). 
The easiest way to find out if is not a number is the function isNumeric().
Put together you will get

```
Sub DeleteLetterRows()

   Dim k as integer
   Dim test As String

   For k = 2 To 100
     test = Left(ActiveSheet.Range("A" & k).value,1)
     If isNumeric(test) = False then
        Rows(k).EntireRow.Delete
     Else
     End If
   Next k

End Sub
```

Comment: but `?` or `-` are neither letters nor numeric so they should not be deleted, but your code would do... (but that may be okay for the OP)

Comment: @DirkReichel I had initially the same concern, that's why I tried to do it the ASC code, but by data set does not have special characters, so it will work for me.